# iTextSharp PDF EN C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows, itextsharp, itextpdf

Estoy creando un pdf con iTextSharp pero al momento de declararlo en el código no me lo reconoce.

Tengo el siguiente código

```
try
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\ACUSE-MANTENIMIENTOS-EQUIPOS");
                Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
                //empezamos a imprimir el documento
                PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\ACUSE-MANTENIMIENTOS-EQUIPOS\" + fechaagria + "-" + equipo + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));

                doc.Open();
                /// Empieza la Tabla    
                **iTextSharp.text.Image imagen = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("./a-la-medida.png");**
                
                imagen.IndentationRight = -50;
                imagen.ScaleToFit(90f, 90f);

                doc.Add(imagen);

                PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

                Paragraph r = new Paragraph("Direccion de atención médica",FontFactory.GetFont("arial",18, BaseColor.BLACK));
                r.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                Paragraph r2 = new Paragraph("\n");

                doc.Add(r);
                doc.Add(r2);

                PdfPCell tituloCelda = new PdfPCell();
                Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Recibo de Pago ",FontFactory.GetFont("arial",14, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK));

                Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("\n",FontFactory.GetFont("arial",14, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK));
                p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                tituloCelda.Colspan = 3;
                tituloCelda.AddElement(p);
                tituloCelda.AddElement(p3);
                table.AddCell(tituloCelda);
                //////////////////////
               



                doc.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
}
```

Lo que pongo en letra negrita C# no me lo reconoce y el documento ya no carga nada después de **''Dirección de Atención Médica''**

AYUDA :(

Comment: Es que después de añadir r y r2 al documento no le añades más. Tienes que añadir p, p3 y table al doc.

Comment: Juan Carlos Guibovich:  se supone que los agrego en este pedazos de código,:  tituloCelda.AddElement(p);
                tituloCelda.AddElement(p3);
                table.AddCell(tituloCelda);    o estoy equivoado?

Comment: Agregas celdas a la tabla, pero la tabla como tal no la agregas a doc

Comment: Como dice jadromero, estas añadiendo celdas a la tabla, ahora te toca añadir la tabla al documento

Comment: @javdromero , tienes razón, gracias!

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich, tienes razón, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo, lo que veo aquí, es que creas una instancia de un documento (Document) y la abres, pero luego no agregas todos los contenidos que quieres en esa misma instancia, a la que has llamado (doc) donde despues esperas tenerlos ..

En cambio agregas ese contenido a una instancia de tabla que llamas table.

Creo que al final, antes de doc.Close();, te faltaría un:

```
doc.Add(table);
```

Prueba así:

```
    try 
        {
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\ACUSE-MANTENIMIENTOS-EQUIPOS");
         Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
         //empezamos a imprimir el documento
         PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\ACUSE-MANTENIMIENTOS-EQUIPOS\" + fechaagria + "-" + equipo + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
    
          doc.Open();
          /// Empieza la Tabla    
                **iTextSharp.text.Image imagen = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("./a-la-medida.png");**
                
                imagen.IndentationRight = -50;
                imagen.ScaleToFit(90f, 90f);

        doc.Add(imagen);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

        Paragraph r = new Paragraph("Direccion de atención médica",FontFactory.GetFont("arial",18, BaseColor.BLACK));
        r.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        Paragraph r2 = new Paragraph("\n");

        doc.Add(r);
        doc.Add(r2);

        PdfPCell tituloCelda = new PdfPCell();
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Recibo de Pago ",FontFactory.GetFont("arial",14, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK));

        Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph("\n",FontFactory.GetFont("arial",14, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD,BaseColor.BLACK));
        p.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                tituloCelda.Colspan = 3;
                tituloCelda.AddElement(p);
                tituloCelda.AddElement(p3);
                table.AddCell(tituloCelda);

    /* No has agregado la tabla y/o los
   contenidos que porta la tabla table
   al Document doc. En la  instancia 
   doc solo has agregado hasta el texto 
   "Dirección de atención medica" y 
   retorno de carro "\n".*/
    
    /*Debes agregar a doc los contenidos
 que te faltan, asi ...*/
        
    doc.Add(table);  


    doc.Close();    
                }        
    catch (Exception ex)
            {
MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
      }
```

Comment: Gracias, me funciono perfecto.